# Is the order in the certificate collection returned by generateCertificates preserved?

Tags: java, ssl

I'm trying to get the list of certificates from an inputStream using generateCertificates API from certificateFactory. The input stream contains a list of certificates. Does the collection returned by the generateCertificates preserve the order in which the certificates are ordered in inputStream?